# Visual Studio's 'Go To Definition' doesn't work on javascript libraries

Tags: visual-studio, javascript-intellisense

I'm using visual studio to edit a basic webpage I'm making, which uses the VisJS library.  Intellisense magically works:

[image]

However, on that same object when I try to 'Go To Definition', it can't find it:

[image]

It would also be really nice to see what parameters the Network constructor takes as well. 
How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar problem on Visual Studio 2017, where Go To Definition wasn't working with JavaScript files.

The solution was going to:

```
Tools > Options > Text Editor > JavaScript/TypeScript > Language Service
```

There are 2 checkboxes there, one of them is:

```
Disable dedicated syntax process (restart required)
```

I unchecked it, restarted VS, and F12 then worked as usual.